# Gstreamer server client with java

Tags: java, android, client-server, gstreamer, video-conferencing

I'm new to [gstreamer](/questions/tagged/gstreamer) and I need some push in the right direction. I need to create a chat application that uses webcams and audio on both ends and uses java to do this. I dont want to install other stuff on the client more than my application. And the server can be used as a connection between the clients OR used on one end.

Comment: what exactly do you expect as answer? where are you stuck? kick in: [use google](https://www.google.sk/search?q=java+gstreamer), you need to provide at least [something](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). and please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: The thing is, I dont know where to start. I need to use java to make it possible for one person to use an android phone and one person to use either an android phone or a PC to have a video conferance with each other and i dont know any good tools for that. I need some advice on where to begin and what to look for. I have been searching alot on google and still can't find anything useful aside from paid services and I need it to be free.

Comment: I dont think StackOverflow is good place to ask these kind of questions. Isnt there some android community forum? I personaly like Qt (it works on Android) I would implement it using Qt and gstreamer.. if you need to use only java then ask on IRC of gstreamer and maybe they will tell you - there is lot of activity on gstreamer and android I think they can guide you.

Comment: also please list some details on what have you tried so far (I guess you know how to deploy Java application on Android.. maybe you have problems binding to gstreamer api..). Maybe [this tutorial](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Android+tutorial+4%3A+A+basic+media+player) can help you..

Comment: @otopolsky this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**